# Stopwatch that counts down in C#

Tags: c#

I've seen variations of this by googling it but I have a windows form with a timer control, three textboxes (hour, minute, second) and based on a button being clicked, I want to count down from 2 hours.  So right after clicking textbox1 (hour) will be 1, textBox2 (minute) will be 59, textBox3 (second) will be 59 and they will all continue to count down until all read 0.

Does anyone have some code to share for that?

Many thanks.

Comment: What have you tried?  What have you thought of?  Are you stuck because you don't know how to do it in C#, or because you don't know how to do it in pseudo-code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the TimeSpan class. Initialize of to 2 hours. If you start the Timer get the current timer. Then with a Timer object refresh your display every second. Simply get the current Time. So the remaining time is:

TimeSpan remaining = twoHoursTimespan - (CurrentTime - StartTime);

Answer (score 3):

Extract the components from a TimeSpan. Record the current time and date as soon as the button is clicked, and store that in a variable. Then, every second your timer should calculate the duration since the start time.

IE: DateTime result = DateTime.Now.Subtract(StartingTime);

Then, use the parts of the resulting TimeSpan to populate the fields.

IE: int Hour = result.Hour; (or something like that).

Addendum: Don't count down manually every second, because this is likely to cause the countdown to be inaccurate.

Answer (score 0):

This tutorial explains very well what you're trying to achieve.

**How To Create A Countdown Timer Application Using C# And WinForms**
[archive.today](https://archive.today/MZhWR) / [archive.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20111211015212/http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/57482-countdown-timer/)

It gives you the option to count down from any given time, not just 2 hours. Of course, you can just set it to 2 hours if it's the only thing you need.

Comment: I'd downvote you for pointing to this abomination but I'm in a good mood today :)

Comment: @Diadistis - what are you talking about ;) It's a great code sample; even down to the default button names of button1, button2, etc.

Comment: @Diadistis I took a look at the article and thought it was ok... but then I saw some of the code and I agree! Why are they using Convert.ToInt32 and catching the exception, sorry, catching Exception - int.TryPrase has been here since version 2.0 (I personally don't like the "if (paused != true)" either but don't know if it's a preference thing)

Comment: This concept of "tick" confuses and infuriates me. I demand a single button solution. Winforms make it really easy to change the text from "start" to "stop" and "pause" is adding unnecessary complexity... (j/k)

Comment: catch (Exception ex)  
 {  
          MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);  
 }  

What the * ??!!!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [Cope Project article and project](http://web1.codeproject.com/KB/cs/timeralarm.aspx) that's in the neighborhood of what you want. Might even meet your needs outright if your needs are flexible.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry this might not be the exact answer, but you will need to use a timespan to achieve this.

```
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;

// get the time elapsed since we started the test
// start date was set somewhere else before this code is called
TimeSpan span = now - _startDate;

// format the time left
String timeleft = span.Hours > 0 ? String.Format( "Time Left - {0}:{1:D2}:{2:D2}", span.Hours, span.Minutes, span.Seconds ) : String.Format( "Time Left - {0:D2}:{1:D2}", span.Minutes, span.Seconds );
```